# Upload attachments to SharePoint in Dynamics CRM 2015 online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dynamics-crm

I have a use case where I am building an internet facing asp.net web form for a user to submit a new record to CRM.  This web form links to a CRM online instance, which is integrated to a SharePoint online instance.  The user that logs into CRM, has access to SP as well.

As part of this new record, I also want to give them the ability to add an attachment, and have that attachment go directly into the SharePoint document library/server that is linked to the CRM instance.

I can see some SharePoint entities listed in the SDK like SharePointData, SharePointDocument, DocumentLocation, and Site, but cannot find any sample code on how to use them, or how to get a file into SP via the SDK?

Any xRM examples out there that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with you're own internet facing asp.net web form, you can also upload the file to SharePoint directly. You just need to have the location to store the file. And I assume you can get that from CRM.

You have two options:

1. Using the SharePoint rest endpoint
2. Or use the SharePoint.Client assembly.

This is the MSDN article for SharePoint online: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn904536.aspx